# React - Use localstorage/sessionStorage to persist login on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, basic-authentication, session-storage

i want to persist login when a page is refreshed and i am using sessionStorage at the moment to set with is logged in or not. (isAuthenticated true/false)

If this flag in sessionStorage is true then i don't show a login form but instead other content, otherwise the login form is shown.

My concern is that someone could just manually add this flag to sessionStorage in their browser to bypass the login form couldn't they?

Comment: With flag in session storage. You should also validate session with some token that will be validated through backend i.e. server. That is the right way to do it.

Comment: ah, so you would need to make another APi call with that token?

Comment: Yes. When user logs in. You should generate token for that session and store it in session storage. and when you make any request to your server. You must validate the token every time. In this case, If user edits the variables in local session storage, then too you will be able to identify the user, whether it is the right user or not.